# Page Action popup not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I used a page action that only shows when I am on a Youtube video, and it works and shows the icon as active. However, the popup does not open when I click on the extension. I have specified the `default_popup` in my manifest file.

I am using a content script that sends a message to the background script which shows the page action. Here is the code:

```
//background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.activate == "true") {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});

//activate.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ activate: "true" });

//manifest.json
"page_action": {
    "default_popup": "/Pages/index.html"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
    "js": ["activate.js"]
}]
```

Moreover, I also tried making the page action shown the whole time by putting `chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id)` outside the onMessage function and it works, the popup shows as expected. How can I fix this issue?

EDIT: Issue fixed, read answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by reading up more on page actions and realizing I need to use  `chrome.declarativeContent`. The rules for defining when a page action is shown are here in the docs: [Define rules for activating the extension...](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/user_interface/#rules)